# Laravel route post vs get

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes, laravel-blade

project is laravel 5.6. My project has 2 routes:

web.php

```
Route::get('testa', 'HomeController@showTestForm')->name('test');
Route::post('testa', 'HomeController@doTest');
```

HomeController :

```
public function showTestForm()
{
    Log::warning('from showTestForm');    
    return view('test');
}

.public function doTest(Request $request)
{
    Log::info('from doTest');    
    // return Input::all();
    return view('test', [
        'input' => implode(', ', Input::all()),
    ]);
}
```

test.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('test') }}">
@csrf

<input type="text" name="inputvalue">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
merge
</button>

</form>

<div>Result</div>
@if(isset($input))
{{$input}}
@endif
```

Why is working post on route('test') ?
Thank you.

Comment: Your form's method is POST, so it should send a POST request and not get. If you'll change the form method to `get` you'll trigger the `Route::get()` method.

Comment: Ok, but why is working post form on get route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `route('test')` works even though your form is a `POST` request is because `route()` is just a helper function to generate a url and your `GET` and `POST` routes both use the same url.

You've specified in your form to make a post request and it's going to send it to the url provided (which will be the same as your `GET` request in this case).

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
Route::post('testa', 'HomeController@doTest')->name('postTest');
```

and then use

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('postTest') }}">
```

Hope this will work

Comment: What don't you understand?  If you used a named route route ->name('foo') you can access it via the bladed using the route('foo') method and if you don't want to use the named route you can access the through the url() method which will connect it via the URL you tell it too.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you'are calling the wrong route.

Change :
`<form method="post" action="{{ route('test') }}">`

to :
`<form method="post" action="{{ url('/testa') }}">`

or follow the previous answer steps (name the post route then call it)

Answer (score 0):

I believe from the OP they are not understanding how the same route can accept both a `GET` request and a `POST` request.

The difference is in how the server receives the data.

Have a read: [HTTP Requests](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)